# Error while deploying alb-ingress-controller: couldn't auto-discover subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I got this error:

> {"level":"error","ts":1676886565.8192506,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.ingress","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"revaturepro-qa3-alb-ingress-controller","namespace":"qa3","error":"couldn't auto-discover subnets: unable to discover at least one subnet"}`

My service account is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-load-balancer-controller
  name: aws-load-balancer-controller
  namespace: kube-system
```

My `alb-ing-controller` IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:GetCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "tag:GetResources",
                "tag:TagResources"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "waf:GetWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone see what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [AWS KB entry for exactly this error message, please try this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-load-balancer-controller-subnets/):

According to the KB, the following tags must be present on the ingress resource inside of kuberentes:

- kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb or kubernetes.io/role/elb
- kubernetes.io/cluster/your-cluster-name (with value shared or owned)

See the KB article for further details.